# How to disAllow minus (-) in text box

Tags: javascript, validation

Here I have a function which only allows numeric and percentage. But it is allowing minus(-), I want to restrict that minus in that script. How can I restrict.Here is my script.Or please suggest me a dirctive for this.

```
function validateQty(el, evt) {
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode != 45 && charCode != 8 && charCode != 37  && (charCode != 46) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        if (charCode == 46) {
            if ((el.value) && (el.value.indexOf('.') >= 0))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return true;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        var number = evt.value.split('.');
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: try this condition `if(parseFloat(el.value) < 0){
return false;
}`

Comment: No Prasad It's allowing minus(-)

Comment: Your function has return true and then more code which never gets executed (because it has returned true already)

Comment: If this helped to solve your problem, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow what you want to be as input. Do something like this.

```js
function restrictInput(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.value.match(/^\d+$|%$/)) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1)
    }
    console.log(e.target.value);
  })
}

restrictInput(document.getElementById("input1"));
restrictInput(document.getElementById("input2"));
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
```

**updated:** As asked by OP. A generic function to handle inputs.

**NOTE:** You can add more restrictions as you want inside this function

Comment: Jtothi Babu nice answer. But it should not be specific to a single text box. I mean you have given id. Is it possible to convert this to a function

Answer (score 1):

You could use `input=number`

```
<input type="number" min="0" />
```

Using javascript you could do:

```
// Select your input element.
var numInput = document.querySelector('input');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
numInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
}, false)
```

If the data from the input field will be sent to the server, make sure to add this validation on the server too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your script by just testing it against a regular expression.

So your function would essentially change to something like this

```
function validateQty(el, evt) 
{
   var regex = new RegExp(/^\d+$|%$/);

   return regex.test(el.value);
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg3cyg3e/2/)